# Windows 10 default mail app - how to mark all unread as read?

Tags: windows, windows-10, email-client

Trying to enjoy Windows 10 on my ElitePad 900 tablet.
Have been searching for this and have not found any solution. So the idea is to mark all unread mails as read ones. Is there a shortcut key or something?

Comment: you can simply mark **all** Mails as read because it won't do anything with those who are already marked as read

Comment: how can I do that? the only solution I have found is to click on each individual mail to wait it to become read, or to mark them all by one and press "mark as read". I connot understand why there's no functionality like to right cick on inbox and click "mark all as read"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. What you can do, and perhaps it is faster if you have really huge heap of email you you really want to make them as read without reading is to switch filter to "unread", than click this icon icon next to refresh on top of list (the one with ticks) ("Select mode").

Than mark with checkboxes all the messages

And finally under the icon with 3 dots ... there is an option "Mark as read".

Comment: this is how I do it now, and it is horrible!! I hope that developers of mail app will deal with this problem in close future.

Comment: I am not sure if this is actually the problem. The problem is rather - why you want to mark mails as read without reading them?
I used this workflow some time ago to differentiate if this is new message or not. But than I  realised that I lost the function to actually know if something was read :)

Comment: because some mails can be understood by just looking at subject (like when someone follows you on twitter), or there are promos that I do not want to read right now, but they are not spam. Or many more cases. The usecase is not he case here, it's the common one to have "mark all as read" button or something, just as cars have 4 doors (average), not just one.

Comment: +krzysdan There is a definite need for a solution here.  I don't use my Microsoft Live email account as my goto.  I will check it once every month.  At these points, I will have hundreds of unread mail, none of which I care about.  Don't presume to solve a different problem.

Comment: When installing fresh windows and connect your existing email account to application - it will mark all the emails as unread, though actually they are read by a user. At least POP

Answer (score 3):

There is a way!

There are keyboard shortcuts. ctrl+A selects all messages! ctrl+q marks them all as read! Or, after using ctrl+A, select the "Mark as read" option at the top. If you do this in your unread folder, you can mark all as read quickly! :D

EDIT: Well, apparently this was for windows 8. ctrl+q marks as unread still, but ctrl+a does nothing. Well, best advice is go to "Unread" folder, click the top email, and spam ctrl+q. That should clear it out faster than anything else. Sorry. :/

Comment: Are you confusing Mail app with Outlook ?

Comment: Just tried this on latest version of Windows 10. Both `ctrl+a` and `ctrl+q` worked as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the first email in the inbox.
Hold down CTRL with your left hand on the left hand side of the keyboard.
Then, press 'down' on your keyboard, then press 'enter'.
'down' 'enter' 'down' 'enter' 'down'

All while holding CTRL!

Then, you can go up and 'mark as read' for the whole lot!

It works, takes a while but is the quickest way I know. Hope I helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Solution :
Go to Outlook.com.
Enter your email account.
Right click on inbox folder.
Mark all as read.
Finish.
Your Windows 10 mail app will synchronize with your
outlook account and will mark all messages as read.

Answer (score 0):

A much faster solution is to simply use the arrow keys to navigate through all messages and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while selecting each unread message. There's no reason to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

For some reason, it seems to take a second or two after you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but the messages are marked as read.